# sql not exists and subquery

Tags: sql, exists

suppose there is a college database

```
name     |  state | enrollment
=============================
Stanford | CA     | 15000
-----------------------------
Berkley  | CA     | 36000
-----------------------------
MIT      | MA     | 10000
-----------------------------
Cornell  | NY     | 21000
```

Without using `max()`, I can get the college with the maximum enrollment using exists operator and a subquery

```
select name from college c1 where not exists ( select * from college c2 where c2.enrollment > c1.enrollment);
```

This returns

```
 Berkeley
(1 row)
```

as expected

Still,I can't understand how the query worked. `exists` condition is met if the subquery returns at least one record.So,in the above ,the `not exists` would be met only if the subquery returns an empty set.Or so  I thought..

To check this ,I tried to run the subquery

```
select c2.name from college c2,college c1 where c2.enrollment > c1.enrollment);
```

But this returns

```
  name   
----------
 Stanford
 Berkeley
 Berkeley
 Berkeley
 Cornell
 Cornell
(6 rows)
```

I am really confused here..can someone clarify how the first query worked and why I am wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select name from college c1 where not exists ( select * from college c2 where 
c2.enrollment > c1.enrollment);
```

The above query looks for records where it can find the enrollment value > current row of the outer query.

Assume that the query runs in a top-down sequence where it will

1. Look at Stanford enrollment & check if any other rows has
   enrollment > Stanford enrollment . The subquery will return 2
   records (Cornell & Berkley). So, it will not be a match.
2. Look at Berkley enrollment & check if any other rows has enrollment > Berkley enrollment. The subquery will return 0 records. Hence `NOT EXISTS` condition will return true for Berkley.

Answer (score 2):

It's fairly straightforward - the query states 'Find me the college where  there aren't any other colleges that have a higher enrollment'

(Note: if you have ties, this will obviously return multiple results)

Your query is stating: 'find me any college where its enrollment is greater than some other college', therefore every single row will be returned except the one with the lowest enrollment (it will also exclude any ties at the lowest level).

Answer (score 1):

After jour cross join and applying WHERE expression you still sometimes have more than one row from c2 for one row from c1. Actually you do very different things in both your queries.

Answer (score 1):

Exists simply tests whether the inner query returns any row. If it does, then the outer query proceeds. If not, the outer query does not execute, and the entire SQL statement returns nothing.

The syntax for EXISTS is:

```
    SELECT "column_name1" FROM "table_name1" WHERE EXISTS(SELECT * FROM "table_name2"
    WHERE [Condition])
```

since the subquery returns more than 0 row, the EXISTS condition is true, and the condition placed inside the inner query does not influence how the outer query is run.

Answer (score 0):

### name

Stanford
 Berkeley
 Berkeley
 Berkeley
 Cornell
 Cornell

are returned as sequence of comparison is given below:

### Stanford | CA     | 15000

### Berkley  | CA     | 36000

### MIT      | MA     | 10000

Cornell  | NY     | 21000

First C2 would be stanford and C1 would be all colleges one by one
stanford is NOT greater than itself,
stanford is NOT greater than berkely,
standford is Greater than MIT,
Stanford is NOT greater than cornell --- this ends first loop giving one stanford

Again in 2nd case c2 would be berkely and C1 would be all colleges from top
gives 3 berkely
and 3rd case nothing
4th case single cornell

thats it